# How can I extract the dominant color of an Image using ImageMagick EXCLUDING white or transparent pixels?

Tags: powershell, imagemagick

I deal a lot with icon design and often need to sort them by color. So I've set out to create a powershell script to do just that, which wraps ImageMagick.

Here's an example folder:

[image]

The simple explanation: I want to separate all blue icons into a sub-folder.
Just as a note: I've tried both SVG and PNG and receive the exact same results. So it's not a file format issue.

I've tried:

```
magick "Lunacy 32px Toolbar Button Tool Selected.svg" +dither -colors 5 -define histogram:unique-colors=true -format "%c" histogram:info:
```

Also tried:

```
magick $File -format %c -depth 8  histogram:info:
```

The last option works the best and actually returns the correct result for images that are not outlined like this one:

[image]

But images like this are not working:

[image]

The image has no white (It's transparent). The histogram is listing transparent pixels only. Hence why I want to disable alpha for this process.

Histogram output:

```
2318: (0,0,0,0) #00000000 none
14: (0,128,255,4) #0080FF04 srgba(0,128,255,0.0156863)
2: (0,128,255,2) #0080FF02 srgba(0,128,255,0.00784314)
6: (0,153,204,5) #0099CC05 srgba(0,153,204,0.0196078)
4: (0,170,255,3) #00AAFF03 srgba(0,170,255,0.0117647)
13: (0,255,255,1) #00FFFF01 srgba(0,255,255,0.00392157)
1: (16,159,223,16) #109FDF10 srgba(16,159,223,0.0627451)
3: (17,153,221,15) #1199DD0F srgba(17,153,221,0.0588235)
2: (18,164,219,14) #12A4DB0E srgba(18,164,219,0.054902)
3: (19,161,227,27) #13A1E31B srgba(19,161,227,0.105882)
1: (20,153,224,25) #1499E019 srgba(20,153,224,0.0980392)
2: (20,154,228,38) #149AE426 srgba(20,154,228,0.14902)
1: (20,157,226,26) #149DE21A srgba(20,157,226,0.101961)
1: (21,149,234,12) #1595EA0C srgba(21,149,234,0.0470588)
1: (21,156,227,36) #159CE324 srgba(21,156,227,0.141176)
1: (21,156,227,72) #159CE348 srgba(21,156,227,0.282353)
2: (21,156,229,49) #159CE531 srgba(21,156,229,0.192157)
1: (21,157,225,60) #159DE13C srgba(21,157,225,0.235294)
1: (21,159,223,24) #159FDF18 srgba(21,159,223,0.0941176)
2: (21,159,226,61) #159FE23D srgba(21,159,226,0.239216)
3: (21,159,227,37) #159FE325 srgba(21,159,227,0.145098)
4: (22,155,222,23) #169BDE17 srgba(22,155,222,0.0901961)
4: (22,155,225,69) #169BE145 srgba(22,155,225,0.270588)
1: (22,155,227,46) #169BE32E srgba(22,155,227,0.180392)
1: (22,156,226,80) #169CE250 srgba(22,156,226,0.313725)
1: (22,156,226,116) #169CE274 srgba(22,156,226,0.454902)
5: (22,156,227,194) #169CE3C2 srgba(22,156,227,0.760784)
3: (22,156,227,137) #169CE389 srgba(22,156,227,0.537255)
1: (22,156,228,93) #169CE45D srgba(22,156,228,0.364706)
1: (22,156,228,103) #169CE467 srgba(22,156,228,0.403922)
3: (22,156,229,59) #169CE53B srgba(22,156,229,0.231373)
3: (22,157,226,114) #169DE272 srgba(22,157,226,0.447059)
2: (22,157,226,115) #169DE273 srgba(22,157,226,0.45098)
3: (22,157,227,138) #169DE38A srgba(22,157,227,0.541176)
2: (22,157,227,171) #169DE3AB srgba(22,157,227,0.670588)
2: (22,157,227,148) #169DE394 srgba(22,157,227,0.580392)
1: (22,157,227,227) #169DE3E3 srgba(22,157,227,0.890196)
1: (22,157,227,193) #169DE3C1 srgba(22,157,227,0.756863)
1: (22,157,227,216) #169DE3D8 srgba(22,157,227,0.847059)
1: (22,157,227,127) #169DE37F srgba(22,157,227,0.498039)
6: (22,157,228,159) #169DE49F srgba(22,157,228,0.623529)
6: (22,157,228,57) #169DE439 srgba(22,157,228,0.223529)
1: (22,157,228,94) #169DE45E srgba(22,157,228,0.368627)
5: (22,158,226,71) #169EE247 srgba(22,158,226,0.278431)
3: (22,158,226,160) #169EE2A0 srgba(22,158,226,0.627451)
2: (22,158,226,105) #169EE269 srgba(22,158,226,0.411765)
2: (22,158,229,58) #169EE53A srgba(22,158,229,0.227451)
5: (22,160,226,35) #16A0E223 srgba(22,160,226,0.137255)
1: (23,155,224,33) #179BE021 srgba(23,155,224,0.129412)
7: (23,155,228,56) #179BE438 srgba(23,155,228,0.219608)
2: (23,156,226,44) #179CE22C srgba(23,156,226,0.172549)
1: (23,156,226,88) #179CE258 srgba(23,156,226,0.345098)
3: (23,156,227,181) #179CE3B5 srgba(23,156,227,0.709804)
2: (23,156,227,90) #179CE35A srgba(23,156,227,0.352941)
2: (23,156,227,111) #179CE36F srgba(23,156,227,0.435294)
2: (23,156,227,176) #179CE3B0 srgba(23,156,227,0.690196)
1: (23,156,227,207) #179CE3CF srgba(23,156,227,0.811765)
6: (23,156,228,67) #179CE443 srgba(23,156,228,0.262745)
2: (23,156,228,168) #179CE4A8 srgba(23,156,228,0.658824)
6: (23,156,229,77) #179CE54D srgba(23,156,229,0.301961)
4: (23,157,226,187) #179DE2BB srgba(23,157,226,0.733333)
3: (23,157,226,78) #179DE24E srgba(23,157,226,0.305882)
3: (23,157,226,214) #179DE2D6 srgba(23,157,226,0.839216)
3: (23,157,226,169) #179DE2A9 srgba(23,157,226,0.662745)
2: (23,157,226,133) #179DE285 srgba(23,157,226,0.521569)
1: (23,157,226,143) #179DE28F srgba(23,157,226,0.560784)
624: (23,157,227,255) #179DE3FF srgba(23,157,227,1)
24: (23,157,227,254) #179DE3FE srgba(23,157,227,0.996078)
24: (23,157,227,249) #179DE3F9 srgba(23,157,227,0.976471)
13: (23,157,227,197) #179DE3C5 srgba(23,157,227,0.772549)
13: (23,157,227,198) #179DE3C6 srgba(23,157,227,0.776471)
11: (23,157,227,248) #179DE3F8 srgba(23,157,227,0.972549)
10: (23,157,227,252) #179DE3FC srgba(23,157,227,0.988235)
10: (23,157,227,235) #179DE3EB srgba(23,157,227,0.921569)
8: (23,157,227,247) #179DE3F7 srgba(23,157,227,0.968627)
7: (23,157,227,253) #179DE3FD srgba(23,157,227,0.992157)
7: (23,157,227,244) #179DE3F4 srgba(23,157,227,0.956863)
6: (23,157,227,222) #179DE3DE srgba(23,157,227,0.870588)
6: (23,157,227,236) #179DE3EC srgba(23,157,227,0.92549)
6: (23,157,227,156) #179DE39C srgba(23,157,227,0.611765)
5: (23,157,227,109) #179DE36D srgba(23,157,227,0.427451)
5: (23,157,227,154) #179DE39A srgba(23,157,227,0.603922)
5: (23,157,227,250) #179DE3FA srgba(23,157,227,0.980392)
5: (23,157,227,221) #179DE3DD srgba(23,157,227,0.866667)
5: (23,157,227,189) #179DE3BD srgba(23,157,227,0.741176)
4: (23,157,227,190) #179DE3BE srgba(23,157,227,0.745098)
4: (23,157,227,192) #179DE3C0 srgba(23,157,227,0.752941)
4: (23,157,227,251) #179DE3FB srgba(23,157,227,0.984314)
4: (23,157,227,243) #179DE3F3 srgba(23,157,227,0.952941)
4: (23,157,227,242) #179DE3F2 srgba(23,157,227,0.94902)
4: (23,157,227,174) #179DE3AE srgba(23,157,227,0.682353)
4: (23,157,227,120) #179DE378 srgba(23,157,227,0.470588)
4: (23,157,227,179) #179DE3B3 srgba(23,157,227,0.701961)
3: (23,157,227,202) #179DE3CA srgba(23,157,227,0.792157)
3: (23,157,227,237) #179DE3ED srgba(23,157,227,0.929412)
3: (23,157,227,200) #179DE3C8 srgba(23,157,227,0.784314)
3: (23,157,227,180) #179DE3B4 srgba(23,157,227,0.705882)
3: (23,157,227,224) #179DE3E0 srgba(23,157,227,0.878431)
3: (23,157,227,211) #179DE3D3 srgba(23,157,227,0.827451)
3: (23,157,227,240) #179DE3F0 srgba(23,157,227,0.941176)
3: (23,157,227,245) #179DE3F5 srgba(23,157,227,0.960784)
3: (23,157,227,246) #179DE3F6 srgba(23,157,227,0.964706)
2: (23,157,227,219) #179DE3DB srgba(23,157,227,0.858824)
2: (23,157,227,239) #179DE3EF srgba(23,157,227,0.937255)
2: (23,157,227,208) #179DE3D0 srgba(23,157,227,0.815686)
2: (23,157,227,210) #179DE3D2 srgba(23,157,227,0.823529)
2: (23,157,227,166) #179DE3A6 srgba(23,157,227,0.65098)
2: (23,157,227,229) #179DE3E5 srgba(23,157,227,0.898039)
2: (23,157,227,226) #179DE3E2 srgba(23,157,227,0.886275)
2: (23,157,227,215) #179DE3D7 srgba(23,157,227,0.843137)
2: (23,157,227,201) #179DE3C9 srgba(23,157,227,0.788235)
1: (23,157,227,241) #179DE3F1 srgba(23,157,227,0.945098)
1: (23,157,227,135) #179DE387 srgba(23,157,227,0.529412)
1: (23,157,227,213) #179DE3D5 srgba(23,157,227,0.835294)
1: (23,157,227,231) #179DE3E7 srgba(23,157,227,0.905882)
1: (23,157,227,164) #179DE3A4 srgba(23,157,227,0.643137)
1: (23,157,227,175) #179DE3AF srgba(23,157,227,0.686275)
1: (23,157,227,230) #179DE3E6 srgba(23,157,227,0.901961)
1: (23,157,227,209) #179DE3D1 srgba(23,157,227,0.819608)
1: (23,157,227,234) #179DE3EA srgba(23,157,227,0.917647)
5: (23,157,228,223) #179DE4DF srgba(23,157,228,0.87451)
4: (23,157,228,158) #179DE49E srgba(23,157,228,0.619608)
1: (23,157,228,167) #179DE4A7 srgba(23,157,228,0.654902)
1: (23,157,228,122) #179DE47A srgba(23,157,228,0.478431)
1: (23,158,225,34) #179EE122 srgba(23,158,225,0.133333)
4: (23,158,226,79) #179EE24F srgba(23,158,226,0.309804)
4: (23,158,226,89) #179EE259 srgba(23,158,226,0.34902)
1: (23,158,226,87) #179EE257 srgba(23,158,226,0.341176)
1: (23,158,226,152) #179EE298 srgba(23,158,226,0.596078)
5: (23,158,227,199) #179EE3C7 srgba(23,158,227,0.780392)
4: (23,158,227,157) #179EE39D srgba(23,158,227,0.615686)
4: (23,158,227,238) #179EE3EE srgba(23,158,227,0.933333)
4: (23,158,227,191) #179EE3BF srgba(23,158,227,0.74902)
3: (23,158,227,55) #179EE337 srgba(23,158,227,0.215686)
3: (23,158,227,100) #179EE364 srgba(23,158,227,0.392157)
2: (23,158,227,170) #179EE3AA srgba(23,158,227,0.666667)
2: (23,158,227,212) #179EE3D4 srgba(23,158,227,0.831373)
2: (23,158,227,110) #179EE36E srgba(23,158,227,0.431373)
1: (23,158,227,165) #179EE3A5 srgba(23,158,227,0.647059)
1: (23,158,227,147) #179EE393 srgba(23,158,227,0.576471)
1: (23,158,227,225) #179EE3E1 srgba(23,158,227,0.882353)
1: (23,158,227,136) #179EE388 srgba(23,158,227,0.533333)
3: (23,158,228,76) #179EE44C srgba(23,158,228,0.298039)
1: (23,158,228,131) #179EE483 srgba(23,158,228,0.513725)
1: (23,158,228,186) #179EE4BA srgba(23,158,228,0.729412)
1: (23,158,228,204) #179EE4CC srgba(23,158,228,0.8)
1: (23,158,228,102) #179EE466 srgba(23,158,228,0.4)
1: (23,158,228,66) #179EE442 srgba(23,158,228,0.258824)
4: (23,158,229,68) #179EE544 srgba(23,158,229,0.266667)
4: (23,162,232,11) #17A2E80B srgba(23,162,232,0.0431373)
2: (23,162,232,22) #17A2E816 srgba(23,162,232,0.0862745)
1: (24,154,225,43) #189AE12B srgba(24,154,225,0.168627)
5: (24,156,227,119) #189CE377 srgba(24,156,227,0.466667)
3: (24,156,227,108) #189CE36C srgba(24,156,227,0.423529)
4: (24,156,228,75) #189CE44B srgba(24,156,228,0.294118)
1: (24,156,228,95) #189CE45F srgba(24,156,228,0.372549)
4: (24,157,226,107) #189DE26B srgba(24,157,226,0.419608)
1: (24,157,226,161) #189DE2A1 srgba(24,157,226,0.631373)
4: (24,157,227,117) #189DE375 srgba(24,157,227,0.458824)
3: (24,157,227,217) #189DE3D9 srgba(24,157,227,0.85098)
3: (24,157,227,128) #189DE380 srgba(24,157,227,0.501961)
2: (24,157,227,184) #189DE3B8 srgba(24,157,227,0.721569)
1: (24,157,227,183) #189DE3B7 srgba(24,157,227,0.717647)
1: (24,157,227,162) #189DE3A2 srgba(24,157,227,0.635294)
3: (24,157,228,141) #189DE48D srgba(24,157,228,0.552941)
2: (24,157,228,130) #189DE482 srgba(24,157,228,0.509804)
2: (24,157,228,65) #189DE441 srgba(24,157,228,0.254902)
1: (24,157,228,140) #189DE48C srgba(24,157,228,0.54902)
1: (24,157,228,86) #189DE456 srgba(24,157,228,0.337255)
1: (24,157,228,195) #189DE4C3 srgba(24,157,228,0.764706)
6: (24,158,225,42) #189EE12A srgba(24,158,225,0.164706)
1: (24,158,226,97) #189EE261 srgba(24,158,226,0.380392)
6: (24,158,227,173) #189EE3AD srgba(24,158,227,0.678431)
5: (24,158,227,139) #189EE38B srgba(24,158,227,0.545098)
4: (24,158,227,118) #189EE376 srgba(24,158,227,0.462745)
8: (24,158,231,21) #189EE715 srgba(24,158,231,0.0823529)
4: (24,159,227,74) #189FE34A srgba(24,159,227,0.290196)
2: (25,155,224,41) #199BE029 srgba(25,155,224,0.160784)
2: (25,155,225,51) #199BE133 srgba(25,155,225,0.2)
2: (25,156,226,62) #199CE23E srgba(25,156,226,0.243137)
3: (25,157,226,52) #199DE234 srgba(25,157,226,0.203922)
12: (26,153,230,20) #1A99E614 srgba(26,153,230,0.0784314)
11: (26,153,230,10) #1A99E60A srgba(26,153,230,0.0392157)
1: (26,153,230,30) #1A99E61E srgba(26,153,230,0.117647)
4: (26,158,229,29) #1A9EE51D srgba(26,158,229,0.113725)
2: (26,158,230,50) #1A9EE632 srgba(26,158,230,0.196078)
1: (26,159,230,40) #1A9FE628 srgba(26,159,230,0.156863)
4: (27,155,228,28) #1B9BE41C srgba(27,155,228,0.109804)
3: (27,161,228,19) #1BA1E413 srgba(27,161,228,0.0745098)
7: (28,170,227,9) #1CAAE309 srgba(28,170,227,0.0352941)
6: (30,150,225,17) #1E96E111 srgba(30,150,225,0.0666667)
2: (32,159,223,8) #209FDF08 srgba(32,159,223,0.0313725)
2: (36,146,219,7) #2492DB07 srgba(36,146,219,0.027451)
3: (43,170,213,6) #2BAAD506 srgba(43,170,213,0.0235294)
```

Anyway, does anyone know a sure-fire way to detect the color of an image using ImageMagick that works even when an image is dominated by transparent pixels? I need it to be as accurate as possible.

Any help immensely appreciated.

Comment: Get the histogram, put that into an array, row by row, sort it by count, if top value is black, then skip that value.  This is an OS scripting issue, not one for Imagemagick

Answer (score 1):

You can use color thresholding in Imagemagick. Just specify two colors spanning the range of blue that you need.

Input:

[image]

```
magick icons.png \( +clone -color-threshold "srgba(0,140,200,0.9)-srgba(30,170,240,1)" \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -background white -alpha background -alpha off icons_blue.png
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, other than the alpha channel seems to be upsetting you. Maybe it will help if we make partially transparent colours all into black, so you are left with only black and the near-opaque colours you are interested in.

I'll actually do it with red here so you can see which pixels are affected in StackOverflow light or dark mode - just change `red` to `black` when experimenting on your machine:

```
magick aucPu.png -fuzz 20% -fill red -opaque none -alpha off result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may work if you get imagemagick to tell you just the avarage color:

```
convert $File -scale 1x1\! -format '%[pixel:s]' info:-
```